# Why an auto_ptr can "seal" a container

Tags: c++, stl, constants, auto-ptr

[auto_ptr on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto_ptr) said that "an auto_ptr containing an STL container may be used to prevent further modification of the container.". It used the following example:

```
auto_ptr<vector<ContainedType> > open_vec(new vector<ContainedType>);

open_vec->push_back(5);
open_vec->push_back(3);

// Transfers control, but now the vector cannot be changed:
auto_ptr<const vector<ContainedType> > closed_vec(open_vec); 

// closed_vec->push_back(8); // Can no longer modify
```

If I uncomment the last line, g++ will report an error as

```
t05.cpp:24: error: passing ‘const std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >’ 
as ‘this’   argument of ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const _Tp&) 
[with _Tp = int, _Alloc = std::allocator<int>]’ discards qualifiers
```

I am curious why after transferring the ownership of this vector, it can no longer be modified?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `closed_vec` pointer holds the type `const vector<ContainedType>`. Because the type is `const`, you can't call any methods on it that aren't also defined as `const` (which means they don't change internal data). Naturally `push_back` is non-const, as it changes the vector, so you can't call it on a const pointer. It doesn't really have anything to do with `auto_ptr`, you could accomplish the same with regular pointers:

```
vector<ContainedType>* open_vec = new vector<ContainedType>();
open_vec->push_back(5);
open_vec->push_back(3);

const vector<ContainedType>* closed_vec = open_vec;
closed_vec->push_back(8); // Fails
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) I overlooked the "const" in closed_vec.

Comment: It _does_ have something to do with auto_ptr. With regular pointers, the old non-const pointer could still be used to modify the container. The non-const auto_ptr will be NULL after the ownership transfer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify the vector because `closed_vec` is a pointer-to-const, so the compiler won't let you modify the pointer (but you could still move the pointer).  To allow modification of the vector, declare `closed_vec` as

```
auto_ptr<vector<ContainedType> > closed_vec(open_vec); // no const anymore
closed_vec->push_back(8); // this now works
```

---

If you had declared the pointer as

```
const auto_ptr<vector<ContainedType> > closed_vec(open_vec);
```

on the other hand, you would be able to change the pointee, but not move the pointer.